# How to install zurb foundation on Linux

Tags: vue.js, zurb-foundation

I am using Linux and need to install Zurb Foundation for emails. I am following the instructions by foundation's readme file but i got this error in terminal.

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --mirror -q https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp.git /home/aleksandar/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f2e4e63d/.git
npm ERR! /home/aleksandar/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-f2e4e63d/.git: Permission denied
npm ERR! 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! /home/aleksandar/.npm/_logs/2019-04-09T11_37_25_470Z/debug.log
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use an other way to install it like NPM Package and yard and bowl or download it from foundation's own site. if you want to install at ez way for all time it's better do this :

First install Node js and open your terminal type this :

```
npm install --global foundation-cli
```

after install it go to your direction like this : ~/user/anyfolder

and type this in your terminal :

```
foundation new
```

Done! you got foundation all file and packages.